# While appending divs, delete older appended divs when there are more than 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, html

Consider the following JQuery loop. It appends this:

```
"<div id='1'>" + feedback + "</div>"
```

1st Question.
I want to increment the id of the appended div after the first one has been appended so that the first appended div's id is 1, the second div's id is 2 and so on.

2nd Question.
When the number of divs reaches 10, I want to delete the first appended div.  Which in our case is:

```
<div id="1">php result</div>
```

This should keep looping and deleting older divs.

Here's the Jquery ajax loop:

```
new get_fb(); 
function get_fb(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "algorithm.php",
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb();}, 8000);
    }).responseText;
    $('#BuzFeed').append("<div id='1'>" + feedback + "</div>");
}
```

Comment: The `new` is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting:

```
var get_fb = (function() {
    var counter = 1;
    return function(){
        var feedback = $.ajax({
            ...
        }).responseText;
        $('#BuzFeed').append("<div id='" + counter + "'>" + feedback + "</div>");
    }
})();
get_fb();
```

and for automatic removal, after

```
var $buzfeed = $('#BuzFeed').append("<div id='" + counter + "'>" + feedback + "</div>");
```

add

```
var $buzfeedDivs = $buzfeed.children('div');
if ($buzfeedDivs.length > 10) { $buzfeedDivs.first().remove(); }
```

Additionally, your code uses some not-so-good practices. The re-write, including my additions would be:

```
var get_fb = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var $buzfeed = $('#BuzFeed');
    return function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html", // based on chat
            url: "algorithm.php"
        }).done(function(feedback) {
            counter += 1;
            var $buzfeedresults = $("<div id='BuzFeedResult" + counter + "'></div>");
            $buzfeedresults.text(feedback);
            $buzfeed.append($buzfeedresults);
            var $buzfeedDivs = $buzfeed.children('div');
            if ($buzfeedDivs.length > 10) { $buzfeedDivs.first().remove(); }
            setTimeout(get_fb, 8000);
        }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var $buzfeedresults = $("<div id='BuzFeedError'></div>");
            $buzfeedresults.text('Error: ' + textStatus);
            if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
                console.error(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };
})();
get_fb();
```

Comment: This would remove the div you just appended.  I think you want `first`.

Comment: You missed something on the counting code, after this edit my ajax won't run.

Comment: Did you copy the ellipses verbatim? Include the original part of your code there. Also, `.success` is deprecated.

Comment: Even though the counting is not working, the main question is answered thanks, and I needed last() actually not first.

Comment: @BlessingThinker Whoops, I forgot to close my IIFE. Fixed

Comment: OK now that's proper, at least the IDs will have real names instead of numbers. Proper!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39854/discussion-between-blessing-thinker-and-forivall)